# XCTestCase class introspection methods doesn't work from code while working from LLDB command line

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsbundle, xctest

I am making a test harness with loading local resources as test data to feed my test class derived from XCTestCase. In order to find a proper path I am calling to bundle:

```
- (void) testMethod
{
     NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
     // some other stuff based on bundle
}
```

unfortunately this returns nil. Further breakdown of issues shows:

```
Class cls = [self class];
NSString *classStr = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
Class cls2 = NSClassFromString(@"XCTestCase");
```

cls, cls2 and classStr are all nil. Whereas when I type above lines into LLDB console it all works properly. What could be the cause of this behaviour?